# simple form collection translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

Using the translation example **[here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/302)** that translates the :male, :female options using Ruby I18n, the form will be:

**View:** _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.input :gender, collection: [:male, :female] %>
```

**Generated HTML:**

```
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
```

So when submitting, the form uses the translated values.

How can I change the view code to submit ["male", "female"] values instead of ["Male", "Female"]?

My best shot so far is pretty ugly:

```
<%= f.input :gender, collection: [:male, :female].map{|v| [t("simple_form.options.user.gender.#{v.to_s}", v] %>
```

Comment: can you just downcase the params in your controller?

Comment: @dax, if the UI is in another language like Portuguese, it generates <option>Masculino</option> which I cannon downcase to male

Comment: ah, okay. i've not really worked with translations, interesting question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your view, you should just use

```
<%= f.input :gender, collection: [:male, :female] %>
```

In your yaml file, you should have

```
simple_form:
  options:
    user: (or defaults:)
      gender:
        male: Male
        female: Female
```

This should **automatically** translate into

```
<option value="male">
  Male
</option>
```

It is the values that will go back to the controller, not the translated words.

If not, there is something wrong...

Comment: Since I had a validates_inclusion_of in my model and simple_form requires the values as symbols, I wrongly assume the problem was in the view and not in the model.