# Rails SimpleForm. translate option labels in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I use Rails 5 and SimpleForm
and try build collection from `enum`, for instance:

```
class User
  enum gender: {
    male: 0,
    female: 1
  }
end
```

and  in simple form:

```
= f.input :gender,
          label: false,
          collection: User.genders,
          label_method: :first,
          value_method: :second
```

So how I can translate `label_method`? Text in `option`s in `select` tag.
Is it possible to do in Rails-way without additional steps like `.map`?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648700/simple-form-i18n-labels

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095480/simple-form-collection-translation

Comment: Pavan, I've got issue with `enum` => Hash, I have found that questions but they don't fit me

Comment: What is the issue? Why provided links don't fit?

Comment: Gerry, because there are provided translation for LABEL FOR FIELD, I need translate `label_method` in collection